# Mercurial says hgrc is untrusted in Emacs, but works fine from the command line

Tags: permissions, emacs, version-control, mercurial

I've got some Mercurial checkouts in a directory that was mounted by root.  Mercurial is usually suspicious of files that aren't mine, but I'm the only user here, so I put:

```
[trusted]
users = root
groups = root
```

in my ~/.hgrc, and now I can use `hg` from the command line with no warnings or errors about anything being untrusted.  So far, great.

But when I try to run, say, `vc-annotate` in Emacs, I get an *Annotate* buffer that says:

```
abort: unknown revision 'Not trusting file /home/me/.../working-copy/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user root, group root
Not trusting file /home/me/.../working-copy/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user root, group root
7648'!
```

The message area says:

```
Running hg annotate -d -n --follow -r... my-file.c...FAILED (status 255)
```

I don't have anything in my .emacs related to vc or hg.  Other commands, like `vc-diff`, work fine.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/ananthakumaran/dotfiles/commit/09b5765b2fe835a546f15fccfb2eafc0442cd3d7

Comment: For those that don't feel like reading a big .el file: vc-hg.el is not using the HGPLAIN env (which is probably a bug), and barfing when trying to interpret localized UI messages (I guess).  This git changeset is somebody manually patching vc-hg.el to fix the problem.  An easier solution: just start emacs with env HGPLAIN set!

Comment: Actually, I guess it's not that simple.  Hmm.